# New Kingston SSD drive fails after 1 week

Tags: ssd

I installed a 128GB Kingston SSD V100 and partitioned into three drives. It worked fine for a while but started to encounter write delay failed messages. The computer was not shut down correctly and after that the drive stopped working entirely.

When it is connected to another computer sometimes Disk Management detects that there are three partitions, other times it causes the computer to hang. Have tried testdisk to analyse and this shows read errors at every cylinder.

Any suggestions for a program that can repair the drive? Was this caused by user-error or faulty hardware?

EDIT: Installing the firmware upgrade from Kingston fixed the problem

Comment: It may still be recoverable, but if you're only looking at a week's worth of data, I'd cut losses and restore from the latest backup.

Comment: why did you split 128gb into 3 partitions?

Comment: I created swap @124MB, root was 8GB and /home was 119GB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say you have a few options.

If you have important data on the drive you can try to access it with a [Linux Live CD](http://www.livecdlist.com/); I recommend [Knoppix](http://www.livecdlist.com/knoppix). See [How to use a Live Linux CD](http://www.nssa.rit.edu/?q=node/66).

If you cannot recover the data with a live CD you will need to get it repaired. SSDs differ from regular HDs since they are more difficult to recover in the event of a failure and will need to be professionally repaired.

If the recovery options fail, I would recommend attempting to reformat the drive, as the drives file system may be corrupt. If this also fails do not attempt any other type of repair. Request a RMA from the manufacture. SSDs are not cheap and you do not want to void your warranty which is likely at least 1 year.

I must also place much emphasis on [importance of backups.](http://data-backup-software-review.toptenreviews.com/why-backup-your-computer.html) This is the most underdone procedure but most often the most valuable.

Comment: While a good answer.  According to your edited post it's not the correct one?